# How to reformat a dataset using python?

Tags: python, csv, dataset

I have a program that needs a csv dataset to be formatted a certain way, I will include below how it needs to be formatted, and then I will give an example of what data I want to reformat.

But basically I was wondering how I should go about reformatting this dataset to compress the dates so it doesn't have an instance for every state, and have it where there is one year for each column and one state for each row, is there a way that I can create a python program that will reformat this for me?

[CSV I want to reformat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKVUA.png)
[The format I need it to be like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMEve.png)

Comment: Yes there is a way. Check out the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org) library. It supports everything you mentioned, and will help you transform your dataset with ease.

Comment: Thank you, I have heard of it, but have never got too much into it, but I will try.